# Same solidity contract compiles in Remix but not using brownie: "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType' "

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, brownie

I am new to solidity coding and have been practicing with some basic contracts.

I've made a contract HotelRoom.sol which compiles and runs as intended in Remix, but when attempting to run 'brownie compile' in VSCode on the same file I am met with the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\ollie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\ollie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 41, in main
    active_project = project.load()
  File "C:\Users\ollie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 768, in load
    return Project(name, project_path)
  File "C:\Users\ollie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 188, in __init__
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\ollie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 245, in load
    self._compile(changed, self._compiler_config, False)
  File "C:\Users\ollie\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\main.py", line 127, in _compile
    json.dump(data, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=2, default=sorted)
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    items = sorted(dct.items())
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'
```

Here is the HotelRoom.sol file, which shows no errors or warnings within VSCode:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract HotelRoom {
    enum Statuses {
        Vacant,
        Occupied
    }
    Statuses currentStatus;

    event Occupy(address _occupant, uint256 _value);

    address payable public owner;
    address public occupant;

    constructor() {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        currentStatus = Statuses.Vacant;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner.");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyWhileVacant() {
        require(currentStatus == Statuses.Vacant, "Currently Occupied.");
        _;
    }

    modifier costs(uint256 _amount) {
        require(msg.value >= _amount, "Not enough Ether provided");
        _;
    }

    receive() external payable onlyWhileVacant costs(2 ether) {
        // 1 eth is the cost, and 1 eth is the deposit to be repaid at check out
        // cost goes to the owner, deposit is held in the smart contract
        currentStatus = Statuses.Occupied;
        owner.transfer(msg.value - 1 ether);
        occupant = msg.sender;
        emit Occupy(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    modifier isOccupant() {
        require(msg.sender == occupant, "You are not the current occupant.");
        _;
    }

    event CheckOut(address _occupant);
    event Evict(address _occupant);

    function checkOut() external isOccupant {
        occupant = address(0);
        currentStatus = Statuses.Vacant;
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(1 ether); // return deposit
        emit CheckOut(msg.sender);
    }

    function evict() external onlyOwner {
        occupant = address(0);
        currentStatus = Statuses.Vacant;
        owner.transfer(1 ether); // owner keeps deposit
        emit Evict(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Why does this not compile in VSCode using brownie? Thanks!

Comment: After some testing I've realised that removing the receive() function lets the brownie compile to execute successfully. As a short term fix I've replaced it with a regular function with the same body.

I am still unsure why the presence of a receive function causes this error however.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue with your contract, the receive is completely unrelated. There's something in the python code.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily it is not related to your Solidity code, this is a Python error. It seems you are trying to compare a string with a null object in `sorted(dct.items())`. This is why it compiles in Remix, but not with Brownie. Make sure `dct.items()` has the right type of objects and it should do the fix.